Git: Recover changes from abandoned Cherry-pick
So today I managed to mess up big time. Timeline:

Started a Cherry pick operation in Visual Studio to show someone how it's done.
Completely forgot about it and continued working for two days
Went to Commit the changes I have made in the last two days and when I was about to press the Commit button, the only available button was the "Abandon" button. So my brain goes: Oh, the Cherry Pick is still active, we can Abandon that now.
Press the Abandon button and have my heart sink seeing that ALL my work from the last two days has been undone. Realize that all the changes I have made were made INSIDE the Cherry pick operation.

Note that the changes I have made have never been committed, just saved to the disk.
Please someone tell me that Git is somewhere still aware of the changes to the files and I can somehow recover them. Please!

If the files are still open in the editor, ctrl-z should be able to bring them back. Most IDEs and editors have auto backup plugins like Local History in VS Code. Check if it's installed.

The cherry-pick itself had finished correctly or you were dealing with conflicts and stuff?

Two days without a commit? Ouch. Remember to commit often.

Do you have history from your IDE? Sounds like git won't be able to help much if changes were reverted before they are at least added.

Nope, using Visual Studio, no local history natively and no plugin installed.
I know, two days without commits, but yesterday and the end of the day I have some errors and I don't like to commit files with errors...

I don't think modern IDEs lack local history... I would expect VS to support it as well (I don't know for sure, I do not use it) but this points to it being there: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lostalloy.LocalHistory-for-Visual-Studio

@JanoRajmond Commits save the data into the database. It's very much encouraged to commit your changes as often as possible even if they are flawed. You can always manipulate them like amending, squashing, dropping, editing when necessary. git stash && git stash apply is also a quick backup. At least, you should run git add to convert all the files into blob objects from which you can recover the contents.

If right now you have changes that are a mixture of the unfinished cherry-pick and the later changes you would like to keep, then I think the really best you can do is commit the whole thing as it is right now onto a commit.... then go back to the previous commit and reapply the cherry-pick and finish it..... then your changes should be the result of:
git diff HEAD..HEAD@{2}

You could try doing a cherry-pick of the mixture commit (git cherry-pick HEAD@{2}) and with some luck there will be little conflicts so that you can get your changes only applied on this cherry-pick (git should be able to see that the changes from the cherry-pick you meant to use as an example were already applied.

But wasn't the (pending) cherry-pick canceled by OP? If so, there's nothing to commit...

Oooooohhhh.... well, luck only helps you so far.
